# How do I find out the domain of logged on user using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, vbscript, internet-explorer-11, activexobject

So I wrote a code a few years as under which restricted access to a webpage in case a user was not logged on to a domain.

This used to work fine till we updated to IE11. Now any user outside domain is able access the webpage. I checked online and found that from IE11, ActiveXObject isn't supported.

Is there any alternative to this?

```
    function GetDetails()
    {
            if(a)
        {
            try
            {
                  var net = new ActiveXObject ( "WScript.NetWork" );
                  var username = net.userName;
                  if((net.UserDomain != "ABC") && (net.UserDomain != "DEF") )
                  {
                     alert("You are not in ABC/DEF domain, you can't use this website...");
                     window.opener='X';
                     window.open('','_parent','');
                     window.close();
                  }
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert("Please change your settings Tools-->Internet Option-->security tab-->Custom Level-->Initialize script activex control-->enable");
                window.opener='X';
                window.open('','_parent','');
                window.close();
            }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer this link and check whether you have configure ActiveX related settings properly or not and if not than try to correct it.

Ref: [Use ActiveX controls for Internet Explorer 11 and Internet Explorer 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/17469/windows-internet-explorer-use-activex-controls)

**Note:** Creating an ActiveXObject on a remote server is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 standards mode, Internet Explorer 10 standards mode, Internet Explorer 11 standards mode, and Windows Store apps or later.

Ref: [ActiveXObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/ActiveXObject)

There is no any alternative because ActiveX can only work with IE browser. In that case you need to modify your code which can work on server side.